# Possible to split Athena result into multiple result files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a scheduled job that runs an AWS Athena query and saves the result as a csv into S3. I need the result file to be split into multiple files (so I can process it in parallel).

Is it possible in Athena to split the result to multiple files?

(Obviously I can do it manually; I'm looking for an out of the box AWS solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible in Athena service, there has no option to configure the output of the query different than query result location and encryption configuration, but you can use CTAS query to do it for instance.

I already answered on the similar question. Please look at:

[How do I Configure file format of AWS Athena results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762871/how-do-i-configure-file-format-of-aws-athena-results/52765848#52765848)